# How can I migrate a site to another site with a different installation profile?

Tags: 8, migrations, installation-profiles, aegir

How can be D8 sites migrated in Aegir between different installation profiles, and not only between platforms using the same installation profile?

There is a solution in Aegir for D6->D7 and D7->D7 migrations, documented [here](https://learn.omega8.cc/migrate-sites-between-installation-profiles-111), but it does not work for D8->D8 migrations.

For D8 sites, the new platform appears as an option in the migrate form, but Aegir is still looking for the old profile in the new platform, and migration fails.

Comment: Do you mean "deploy"?

Comment: No, the D8 site is already deployed on Aegir, I want to migrate it into an other platform, which was created via other install profile.

Comment: I don't think there is a tested way to do this currently. If there is a documented way do do this in general for D8 then you might be able to first migrate to a platform that has both profiles and then follow those steps. Afterwards you could migrate to a platform with only the new profile.

Comment: Please create an issue for this at https://www.drupal.org/project/provision.  Patches welcome!

Comment: ...or funding so that we may fix it. ;)